# Is custom font face supported for webbrowsers in wp8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, browser, font-face

Does the web browser control for wp8 support htmls with custom font-face?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) control in Microsoft.Phone.Controls namespace. Yes, it supports standard HTML, which includes HTML/CSS that contains text with a custom font face.

To see this in action, you can try navigating the browser control to any public web page using the [Navigate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff403407%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) method.

Comment: yes I was referring to the WebBrowser control in Microsoft.Phone.Controls namespace. In my scenario, when I tested with an hosted html page with font face in web browser control , it rendered properly. But when I loaded the same file from my isolated store (the fonts are also present in the isolated storage) , it doesn't render the fonts. Am I missing anything?